# is there an open source library which mimics the folder animation on iOS

Tags: ios

i want to mimic the folder animation. is there an open source library which mimics the folder animation on iOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the creator of [**`JWFolders`**](https://github.com/jwilling/JWFolders) which is located on GitHub. Enjoy!

[image]

Comment: hi Jonathan Willing:  yes, i use JWFolder in my project , and not only add a notch on it, also other enhancements. thanks for your sharing the fantastic library.

Comment: @guoleii: Glad it was of use to you. Mind adding a pull request for your repo (if it's on GitHub) with the changes you made?  I'd love see what you've done.

Comment: @guoleii: Okay, I just found your fork. I'll look over it more carefully when I get a chance, but right now it looks like the code is is too complex for my tastes. Call me crazy but I prefer to have succinct code that is easy to debug. If you don't mind, could you add a demo to your project so I can see it up and running? If I like the changes, I'll cherry-pick parts of your fork into the main repo. I hope to have some time on the weekend to actually update this like I'd like to...

Comment: @Jonathan: o , maybe there is a mistake, i have not uploaded my code or forked on Github. Partly because it is too related with my own project. But after finishing my project , i will make it more general and upload it to Github. Thanks

Comment: @Jonathan: i checked the fork page of JWFolder, maybe the branch you mentioned is from "vhbit"

Comment: @guoleii: Ah, yes.  I assumed that was your fork.

Answer (score 1):

hope this one will help you

http://www.scoop.it/t/utbildning-pa-natet/p/1056439145/jwfolders-mimic-the-folder-animation-present-on-the-ios-springboard